# Feasibility of counting Hoffman-Singleton graph cycles?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

I know that counting all distinct simple cycles in an arbitrary graph has exponential time complexity, but what does that really mean in terms of trying to compute the number of cycles in say the Hoffman Singleton Graph?  (50 vertices, 175 edges, 7-regular)  Say I implement a basic algorithm in Java (the one language I've recently learned to code in) and run this program on my run-of-the-mill laptop, could I compute it letting my computer run straight for a couple of days?

Comment: It sounds very feasible, this has probably already been done though

Comment: I can't seem to find anyone mentioning how many cycles it has on the web.  I'd really like to know the answer either way.

Comment: c++ is considerably faster than java and has similar syntax

Comment: what is the algorith, u considered

Comment: I haven't considered any yet, I wanted to know if the computation for such a large graph could even be handled in a reasonable amount of time.  I figured I would just try writing my own program in Java as practice (supposing such a thing could have a feasible run time)  Say I teach myself some C++ over the Winter break, what's a good resource to find C++ cycle-counting algorithms?  Google scholar?